# how to display a pop message in html

Tags: html, vb.net

I have a website that verify NIC. everything work well.. I need to pop up a message when the NIC is not found. below is the backend code:

```
    If StrAction = "NOCONTACT" Then
                ........
end if
```

Comment: Is this using web forms, MVC, or something else?

Comment: If it's web forms, then [Using a Javascript alert in VB.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22245900/1115360) should get you started.